# ElasticSearch ranking - scoring

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We are developing an app with java and using elasticsearch java api. We indexed metadatas and want to use ranking/scoring at indexing time or searching time.

And also, I dunno if it is possible to rank/score a result which is choosed/approved by the users when they click a result. It is like to set that result is a popular result and increase its popularity.

How to implement them? Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elasticsearch is allow us to change/modify the elasticsearch score using the `_score`.

I hope your requirement is to maintain custom ranking in documents rather than the elasticsearch scoring.

if so you need to design the document like that. Add a filed name like `userRank` in all the documents and increment the value if a user click the document in the result. using [function_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_score_functions) you can add the `userRank` field value to the calculated `_score`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a large and complex field called [learning to rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank) that studies how to turn quality information about documents/queries and turn them into relevance ranking rules.

For Elasticsearch specifically, there is [this plugin](https://github.com/o19s/elasticsearch-learning-to-rank) that could help. (disclaimer I'm the creator).